# Is there equivalent `int,short,long` in Perl?

Tags: perl

64bits system:

```
$i=2;print ~$i; # 18446744073709551613
```

32bits system:

```
$i=2;print ~$i; # 4294967293
```

How can I make `$i` 32 bits?

I need a portable bitwise operation in Perl in any system.

Comment: The answer to your headline question is 'No'; there aren't equivalents to `int`, `short` or `long` in Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For portable bitwise operations in Perl, check out the [Bit::Vector library](http://search.cpan.org/~stbey/Bit-Vector-7.1/Vector.pod) on CPAN.

It supports a wide range of bitwise operations, for example:

```
use Bit::Vector;

my $vector = Bit::Vector->new_Dec(32, "2"); # 32-bit vector for the decimal value 2
$vector->Negate($vector);
```

Answer (score 10):

Just bitwise-and the result with `0xffffffff`. This will have no effect on a 32-bit system, and give you the low-order 32 bits on a 64-bit system, which is the answer you want.